# Hard drive full, can't empty trash

Tags: partitioning

I tried to download something very large (not with a browser), but my hard drive didn't have enough space for it. When I tried to delete it again I couldn't empty the trash can (I tried right mouse on trash can and click empty)  .

My drive is now completely full and I can't empty it. I should have almost 80 GB free on another hard drive, but for some reason I can't use it. It says I don't have permission for it and the only files on it are made by root. When I type:
"sudo fdisk -l ' it says the 80 GB drive is bootable.
Ubuntu version 16.04 LTS

Is there any way I can use the 80 GB drive (maybe partition it)?

((How do I empty the trash when my drive is full? EDIT: solved))

Comment: I got part of it myself now. I deleted something with apt and then I could empty my trash. I still can't access the 80 GB drive.

Comment: run `sudo apt-get clean` to get some little space, you can then use `sudo -rf file` from terminal to force remove files

Answer (score 1):

When the root partition fills up in Linux, it's hard to do anything.

Run **sudo apt clean** and **sudo apt autoclean** and **sudo apt autoremove** to give yourself enough room on the hard drive to function.

Then start removing/uninstalling whatever you don't need, or increase the size of your root partition.

Answer (score 0):

How to solve the problem with your 80 GB drive:
`sudo chown <your username here> /dev/sdxx` (you must insert the right name for your drive)